# Share a device across multiple networks in a building

Tags: networking, router

Imagine the following situation:

A building where each apartment has its own network, inside it there's a Smart Home hub that controls multiple IoT devices only inside that block.

Now, let's say that I want the tenants to be able to control their **common** garage door (a simple switch), security cameras or even a doorbell. For the sake of simplicity, consider all of them have an ethernet port.

What kind of network setup/bridge should I have where to allow that device to be "connected" to all the separate networks?

## My idea

My initial naive approach is to have a switch that connects one specific device to all the individual (tenants) networks in the whole building.

However, my primary concern is security. I want the apartment routers to be able to detect the common IoT device. But I don't want the router from apartment A to be able to connect/detect the router in apartment B through the switch.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

[Image: A diagram reflecting an idea of the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grksj.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "detect" (the common IoT devices)? Because automatic detection implies broadcasts, which will require that all apartments share the same subnet, which is something you don't want from a security point of view. Are you OK with configuring the common devices manually, by entering their IP addresses manually in the Tablets/Phones/Laptops of the tenants?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one single Router for everything and one Switch per apartment, as well as one Switch for the common stuff.

Each apartment will have its own subnet (for example 10.111.0.0, 10.112.0.0, 10.113.0.0, ...), and within the subnet each device can see the other one. One Switch per subnet will allow the tenants to connect their devices to it (Wi-Fi, PC, TV). Then the commons stuff will also have its own subnet with a Switch to connect the devices to it (for example 10.110.0.0).

Then each Switch gets one cable to the one single Router, and the Router will need to be configured as the Gateway to the common Subnet 10.110.0.0 (or possibly also the Gateway for everything (0.0.0.0) if it is also used to provide the Internet connection for all apartments).

Then the Router will also need some Firewall rules which prohibit traffic between the subnets of the apartments, which is pretty trivial. It can be as trivial as "Drop all traffic from port 1 (apartment 1) to any port which is not port 0 (internet access, if it exists) and not port 10 (common IoT subnet). Drop all traffic from port 2 to any port but 0 and 10, ...)

The only drawback with this approach is that you need the tenants to configure the shared IoT devices manually. For example the security cameras will be 10.110.1.1, 10.110.1.2 and 10.110.1.3, the Bell will be at 10.110.2.1, the Garage Door at 10.110.2.2. It will not be possible to simply let the tenants click some "Search" button, since they will be on a different subnet and therefore there will be no Broadcasts or other special Packets sent by the devices for the others to detect them.

Such a Router could be a simple device like https://mikrotik.com/product/rb4011igs_rm or https://mikrotik.com/product/RB750Gr3 which would provide 1 port for internet, one for common stuff, and 8 (or 3 respectively) for apartments. Ubiquiti offers very similar ones. The Switches can be any off the shelf Gigabit Switch with around 5 ports (that should be enough)

To reference your image: replace Router A with Switch A, Router B with Switch B, and the "Switch with the blue exclamation mark" with a Router. And add one Switch for the IoT devices.

[image]

If each apartment has its own internet access, then it will get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Daniel. I appreciate the level of detail. The fact that each device has to be set manually is inconvenient, but not the end of the world. In your diagram, you specify a single router for everything, does that suppose the internet connection is shared among apartments? Because the ideal situation would be an individual paid internet plan per apartment.

Comment: If each apartment has its own internet access, then it will be very tricky, but possible. I couldn't help you with that, because the there are too many unknowns, ie, "I believe" that each router from each tenant would then need a manual entry into the routing table so that they know where they can find the common subnet, and this is something which can't be done on commodity hardware. I hope somebody else can give you a good solution for this.